# JS : console.log displays "undefined" in the end of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, console.log

I wanted to display a simple array's items on the console, using foreach. It dispalys all the items(it's OK), but it displays "cars : undefined" at the end.
I dont want to display "cars : undefined", but only the 3 items of the array.
How to do ?

```js
var cars = [{
    year: 2011,
    type: "Volvo"
}, {
    year: 1999,
    type: "Volvo"
}, {
    year: 2003,
    type: "Volvo"
}];
console.log("1");

console.log("cars : " + cars.forEach(a => console.log(a)));
console.log("2");
```

Comment: `forEach()` returns `undefined`. You're logging that value.

Comment: The forEach never returns anything, so undefined is correct

Comment: you could use a map, if you want to return something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach()` returns `undefined`. try like this

```
var cars = [{
    year: 2011,
    type: "Volvo"
}, {
    year: 1999,
    type: "Volvo"
}, {
    year: 2003,
    type: "Volvo"
}];
console.log("1");

console.log("cars : ");
cars.forEach(a => console.log(a))
console.log("2");
```

Answer (score 2):

console.log outputs a string, but returns undefined. So, the inner one writes your data, returns undefined, and the outer one writes 'cars: undefined'

=> You should produce a string inside the log function, like this :

```
console.log("cars :" + cars.map(a => ` ${a.type} ${a.year}` ));
```

That will log:

```
cars : Volvo 2011, Volvo 1999, Volvo 2003
```